# Add notification to mpv through notify.send?

Tags: mpv, notify-send

Is it possible to generate a brief notification every time mpv starts a playback? Maybe through `notify-send`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mpv` can run **lua** user scripts, some of which are listed [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/User-Scripts). One of these, [notify](https://github.com/rohieb/mpv-notify) will generate a sophisticated `notify-send`. It has a few dependencies, and I wasn't able to get it to work in my setup, but the followed greatly simplified code worked for me. Place this file in 
`~/.config/mpv/scripts/mynotify.lua` (create the directory if needed), and run `mpv` as usual. You should see a notification when the artist or title changes.

```
-- based on https://github.com/rohieb/mpv-notify
-- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/455198/119298
lastcommand = nil
function string.shellescape(str)
   return "'"..string.gsub(str, "'", "'\"'\"'").."'"
end
function do_notify(a,b)
   local command = ("notify-send -a mpv -- %s %s"):format(a:shellescape(), 
                                                          b:shellescape())
   if command ~= lastcommand then
      os.execute(command)
      lastcommand = command
   end
end
function notify_current_track()
   data = mp.get_property_native("metadata")
   if data then
      local artist = (data["ARTIST"] or data["artist"] or " ")
      local title = (data["TITLE"] or data["title"] or " ")
      if artist..title~="  " then
         do_notify(artist, title)
         return
      end
   end
   local data = mp.get_property("path")
   if data then
      local file = data:gsub("^.-([^/]+)$","%1")
      file = file:gsub("%....$","") -- delete 3 char suffix
      local dir = data:gsub("^.-([^/]+)/[^/]*$","%1")
      do_notify(dir, file)
   end
end

mp.register_event("file-loaded", notify_current_track)
```

This updated version waits for events that are sent when a new file is ready to be played. It tries to find the metadata and extract the artist and title from it. If this is empty, it then gets the current filename (`"path"`) and splits out the last part after `/` to get a filename, from which it removes any trailing 3 character suffix. It tries to find the last directory part of the filename, and uses these 2 items in the notification. If your directories are structured with say, *artist/albumname/tracktitle.aac*, you might like to change this with a more appropriate pattern match and extraction.  See the lua section on [patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1).

Comment: yeah, i could't make `notify` to work either, that's why i'm asking. I tried your script but i got this error: `[mynotify] Lua error: /home/user/.config/mpv/scripts/mynotify.lua:5: bad argument #1 to 'gsub' (string expected, got nil)`

Comment: As I said, it is greatly simplified. For example, your metadata may not have an artist or title, so you will get an error. I've changed the answer to not crash in this case, or if the keyword is in uppercase, but you may then get notifications with no text. You need to add whatever metadata keys are of interest to you, and exist in your files. I just had some simple id3 tags for mp3 audio files.

Comment: thanks!, I don't think my files have metadata, because they are all aac files. is it possible to modify your script to show only the filenames?

Comment: I've updated the answer to cope with no metadata and some simple filename parsing. You should probably accept this answer and move on to a new question for help on lua.

Answer (score 0):

`mpv` has an event hook library, `libmpv`. There's a issue asking for essentially the same thing here titled: [libmpv event hooking in C# #3810](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/3810).

There's a comment on that issue with a screenshot:

[image: ss #1]

From looking this thread it looks like `mpv` is at least somewhat capable of doing what you want. I believe you'll have to write some code though to implement what you want.

#### Exploring D-Bus

The other way to approach this on the off chance that `mpv` is already sending message via D-Bus is to use the cli tool `dbus-monitor`. With this tool you'll be able to catch all the events being logged, and perhaps you'll be able to catch ones coming from `mpv`.

```
$ sudo dbus-monitor --system
```

**NOTE:** `mpv` is a fork of `mplayer2` and I know `mplayer2` does utilize D-Bus so I would expect `mpv` to do the same.

#### References

- https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/tree/master/libmpv
- https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv
- [Exploring D-Bus](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingDBus)